# Debugging in Firefox Developer Edition yields WSFederationMessageException: ID3204

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, firefox, windows-authentication, ws-federation

I really like Firefox Developer Edition but in the past I have found multiple issues when just trying to get it going which have often required administrator intervention at other places I've worked. The latest issue I'm running into is that when trying to log into some web application I'm debugging (named XXX.YYY) at a new client site, I get the following server error. I don't get this when I use Internet Explorer as my browser. What can I do to correct it?

> Server Error in '/XXX.YYY' Application. ID3204:
>   WS-Federation SignIn request must specify a 'wtrealm' or 'wreply'
>   parameter. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationMessageException:
>   ID3204: WS-Federation SignIn request must specify a 'wtrealm' or
>   'wreply' parameter.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [WSFederationMessageException: ID3204: WS-Federation SignIn request
>   must specify a 'wtrealm' or 'wreply' parameter.]
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.SignInRequestMessage..ctor(Uri
>   baseUrl, String realm, String reply) +271
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationMessage.CreateFromNameValueCollection(Uri
>   baseUrl, NameValueCollection collection) +753
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationMessage.TryCreateFromUri(Uri
>   requestUri, WSFederationMessage& fedMsg) +57
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSignOutCleanupMessage(HttpRequest
>   request) +34
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CanReadSignInResponse(HttpRequest
>   request, Boolean onPage) +188
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args) +85
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +142    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1590.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution! It turns out the issue was that Firefox Developer Edition by default will not authenticate with the Windows NT LAN Manager (NTLM) protocol the way IE does out of the box. So, you have to configure it to do so:

1. Open Firefox Developer Edition and type in *about:config* in the address bar. You will be
   prompted with a warning. Click the "I accept the risk!" button.
2. Use the ‘Search’ field at the top of the browser just below the address bar to find the *network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris* configuration parameter.
3. Double-click the name of the configuration parameter, or right-click it and select Modify.
4. Enter the URLs of the sites you're having trouble authenticating to. Use the format:
   *https://localhost*

There is no need to specify a port number nor a path to any particular page because authentication works on a site by site basis. You can list more than one site by comma-delimiting them. Now, my XXX.YYY web app which I was trying to debug locally runs and authenticates just fine!

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could mark your solution as the answer. Thanks for your sharing.